# ApolloClient not setting authorization header

Tags: react-native, graphql, expo, apollo

I have an expo app that is using a graphql api endpoint. I am attempting to pass an authorization token with each request, but my set up does not seems to be setting or sending my authorization header. In my graphql.config.yml I can set the authorization header here like this and it works:

```yml
schema: schema.graphql
extensions:
  endpoints:
    Dev Backend:
      url: http://localhost:8000/graphql
      introspect: true
      headers:
        authorization: "My token"
```

But in my actual client setup code it is not setting my authorization header. The headers being logged on the backend look like this:

```
Headers({
    'content-length': '113',
    'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    'host': 'localhost:8000',
    'connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'user-agent': 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.7)',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip,deflate'
})
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```js
import {ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloLink, concat} from '@apollo/client';
import {setContext} from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import {getUserSession} from "./session-handler";
import {createUploadLink} from "apollo-upload-client"; // Import AsyncStorage from the correct package
    
// Create an HTTP link to your GraphQL server
const httpLink = createUploadLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:8000/',
  credentials: 'include',
});
    
const authMiddleware = new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
  // add the authorization to the headers
  operation.setContext(({ headers = {} }) => ({
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: "THIS IS A TEST TOKEN",
    }
  }));
    
  return forward(operation);
})
    
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: concat(authMiddleware, httpLink),
});
    
export {
  client
};
```

Comment: See https://michelfloyd.hashnode.dev/jwt-authentication-in-apollo-v4-part-1 for a working auth example with Apollo and Expo.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and the issue was related to frontend and backend code. My JWT secret key was not encoded in base64 (so I encoded it to base64) and I was not passing "Bearer" at the beginning of my token on the frontend.